# UICollectionView does not load all visible cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a `UICollectionView` with some headers and (various-sized) cells. The issue I got with it's that it looks like it doesn't load all the required cells to fill the visible area, but instead it only loads the latest one after I scroll a bit:

[image: UICollectionView bug]

If I remove the headers the issue is gone, which made me suspect that my `collectionView(_:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:)` method to be at culprit, but even if I return a fixed size it still exhibits the same issue.

Can someone help me understand what's happening here? [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17IyLn1yNpeMOLe_I_Amu-7RatyXbOI-H/view) is a demo project with the issue, if someone is interested.

Answer (score 2):

With this line:

```
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

you are not giving the Flow Layout any **hint** as to the item size.

So, Flow Layout essentially says:

- I need another "row" of cells
- the cell *may be as wide as the collection view*
- so, just ask for ***One*** cell

as you start to scroll, the currently visible cell has defined its width, so the Flow Layout asks for another cell.

You can either provide an actual estimated item size, or override `viewDidAppear()` and do it there:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if let fl = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        // let's use estimated width of 40% so we know we can fit 2 cells per row
        //  use a "reasonable" value for the height
        fl.estimatedItemSize = .init(width: collectionView.frame.width * 0.4, height: 280.0)
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

As you state in your comment, this doesn't quite work.

Experimenting a little bit, and changing `0.4` to `0.2` (which seems silly, but...) appears to fix it.

Couple notes though:

From my experience, it is much easier to manage layout like this if we set:

```
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
```

It appears collection view might be trying to allow for multiple "gaps" - causing it to believe only one cell will fit the width.

Then, in `cellForItemAt` set your `.hConstraint`:

```
cell.hConstraint.constant = floor(collectionView.frame.size.width / 2)
```

That gives this output:

[image]

which is, IMHO, a little bit better visual than the original (10, 10) line/item spacing:

[image]

You can adjust the `Bordered View` top/leading/trailing/bottom constraints if you want a little more "padding".

Comment: I'm still seeing the same behavior even after using a fixed size as an estimated. Playing a bit with the `height` and setting it to `80.0` made the situation a bit better, but the issue reappear after scrolling 2 - 3 lines.

Comment: @ov1d1u - are your "Coupon" cells going to have a constant height? Or variable? "A" or "B" in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6c1G.png

Comment: they don't. Initially I used `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`, but I dropped it because I couldn't get one of the coupon cells to grow when the other cell in the same row was a bit taller.

Comment: @ov1d1u - did that solve the issue? If not, you may want to use a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` ... Will this have just those two sections - "Banner" and "Coupons"? Or will it have more sections? And, you weren't clear -- "A" to "B" layout in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6c1G.png for the Coupons?

Comment: @ov1d1u - are you still trying to solve this? If so, I can give you a custom collection view layout class as an alternative.